# YouTubeにアップできるMotion-JPEGの作り方

Tags: android

現在、Androidで簡単な動画を作成するソフトを組んでいます。アニメーションGIFが作れる仕様で作ったのですが、やはり出力サイズが大きく、SNSでの使い回しも不便であるためMotion-JPEGで作り変えることは出来ないか思案中です。

かなり調べたつもりなのですが、どうしても「ちゃんとした仕様は有りません」的な答えばかり出てきて煮詰まっています。ちゃんとした仕様はないにせよ、現にYouTubeにアップできるMotion-JPEGは有るため、デファクトスタンダードは有るのではと思うのでそれが知りたいのです。

参考になるソースなどあればベストなのですが、ご存知の方はおられませんでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。拝見しました所、ヘッダーもなくjpegが羅列しているとして読み取るクラスのようです。念のため手持ちのjpegファイルをバイナリー連結してYouTubeにあげてみましたが、やはりダメのようです。

Comment: @MOW [Motion-JPEG(MJPEG)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG)は動画コーデックにすぎないため、全体を"動画ファイル"として認識させるには、適切なファイルフォーマットに格納する必要があります。一般にはQT(QuickTime)形式, AVI形式あたりに格納することになります。

Comment: Stackovetflowを使い慣れていなくてご迷惑をおかけしました。いろいろありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVIの構造を調べるうちに、求めるもの ほぼズバリのソースがGithubで見つかりましたので、何とかなりそうです。
　https://github.com/abe64/MovieExport-1/tree/master/src/main/java/org/gephi/rs/export/movie/riff

助言くださった方に深く感謝いたします。

//----------　2015/02/26 追補
　件のソースですが、仕上がる動画の画面アスペクト比が16:9固定になっているため、それ以外の比率で作った動画をyoutubeにアップするとに変形してしまうようです。

問題の箇所は MotionJPEG.javaの190行目、

```
 videoPropertiesHeader.setDwFrameAspectRatio(1048585);
```

の部分。ここを

```
Point p = calcAspect(width, height);
videoPropertiesHeader.setDwFrameAspectRatio(p.x * 0x10000 + p.y);
```

と書き直し、アスペクトを割り出す

```
    private Point calcAspect(int w,int h)
    {
        TreeMap<Float, Point> map = new TreeMap<Float, Point>();
        float rate = (float)w / h;

        for(int i=1;i<256;i++)
        {
            float rateMulti = rate * i;
            int rateInt = (int) rateMulti;
            float rateDot = rateMulti - rateInt;
            rateDot = Math.round(rateDot * 1000f) / 1000f;
            Point point = new Point(rateInt,i);
            if(rateDot == 0) return point;
            if(!map.containsKey(Float.valueOf(rateDot))) map.put(Float.valueOf(rateDot), point);
        }
//      for(Entry<Float, Point> e:map.entrySet()) log("G", "map (" + e.getKey() + " , " + e.getValue() +")");
        return map.firstEntry().getValue();
    }
```

こんなメソッドを用意して対処しました。（もっと簡潔な書き方が有るかもしれませんが。）

誰かのお役に立てばいいのですが。